# How to expose manytomany field as a resource with tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

In my current code, a user has a list of goals he has joined. I want an API endpoint to expose all of the user's joined goals. I want to be able to post, put, and get to this API endpoint. It will get a list of the joined goals, add a goal to the joined goals list, or make an update to the joined goals list.

```
# Joined Goal Resource
class JoinedGoalResource(ModelResource):
  user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
  joined_goals = fields.ManyToManyField(GoalResource, 'joined_goals', full=True)

  class Meta:
    authentication = Authentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'joined_goal'
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
    filtering = {
      'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that it uses UserProfile model as its queryset so if I do a post, get, or put on the API endpoint, it will effect the UserProfile rather than the user's joined_goals.

Edit:
I have changed my code so that the joined resource overrides the obj_create method and just adds to the logged in user's joined goal list. The problem is that the method requires me to return a bundle. How do I create the bundle to return? I am doing something like this:

```
goal_resource = GoalResource
goal_obj = goal_resource.obj_get(pk=1)
goal_bundle = goal_resource.build_bundle(obj=goal_obj, request=request)
return goal_bundle
```

But the obj_get doesn't work when taking in an argument of pk=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be quite simple.

You could implement a regular resource (forgetting about user ownership) and then follow the ["Creating per-user resources" section of Tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources) to narrow the list returned by GET and ensure that the newly created objects are owned by the current user (POST).

With respect to PUT, you just need authorization class which ensures the user is only authorized to update his/her own goals. This is the trickiest part (but not hard), just make sure that the value of `user` attribute of the `goal` bundle is the same a `request.user` when the method is PUT otherwise raise an exception and you're done :)

So with above you'd have following URIs:

```
GET,POST,PUT /api/users/ #for interaction with Users
GET,POST,PUT /api/user-goals/ #for interaction with Goals
```

and you could introduce (for GET):

```
GET /api/users/goals/ #for displaying user goals in more natural way
```

by following [Nested Resources section of the cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources)

Comment: It would be very nice to see a solution about the "triciest part" because the are more and more questions like this [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613522/how-to-put-product-to-cart-via-tasytpie-api) [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111734/tastypie-add-element-to-a-many-to-many-relationship) Q1 was my reason for registering on stackoverflow :)

Comment: So someone should post a good question. This question was about how to expose the objects and how to interact with them and I think I answered it. I also gave guidelines on how to implement the part you're mentioning. It's not hard, it only requires a bit of effort to see how ModelResource works and what calls what, so if you like please ask a question, show us what you've tried and where you hit a problem and I'll be happy to help. SO is not meant to be "write code for me" site though.

Comment: And I think that I fullfilled every point in Q1 3 months ago.

Comment: @kgr, Under obj_create, since I am adding to a user profile's list, I am not actually creating any new object, how do I get a bundle to return? I added some code to the main post.

Comment: @egidra, in which resource did you put that code? Do you have two resources as I proposed (`User` and `Goal`) ? I see you've inherited from `ModelResource`, and therefore you shouldn't have to manually write obj_create, except what is shown in the cookbook (this belongs in `Goal` resource)...

Comment: I have the two resources as you proposed. I have to manually write the obj_create. Or else, how will the resource know that it needs to add a goal to a user's goal list? For a post on the goal list, I have to manually do a lookup on a user's UserProfile, look up the goal id from the Goals, and then add the Goal to the UserProfile's goal_list attribute.

Comment: I think you don't. The `Goal` resource should have an `user` attribute (which should result from ForeignKey in the database model), when creating new `goal` you send the URI of appropriate `user` object (e.g. '/api/users/1/') and the connection will be made automatically.