# updating tastypie resource with ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, tastypie

So, I've got my User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
```

and my UserResource:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    followers = fields.ToManyField('self', 'followers', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'followers']

        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

I get this response from API for /api/v1/user/1:

```
{"email": "root@root.com", "followers": [{"email": "asf@afa.com", "followers": [], "resource_uri": "", "username": "123"}], "resource_uri": "", "username": "root@root.com"}
```

Let's pretend I want to add this follower to user:

```
var follower = JSON.stringify({
    {"email": "new@mail.com", "followers": [], "resource_uri": "", "username": "new"}
});
```

How do I create my AJAX request? Any help is appreciated, I'm stuck.

Comment: Have a look here http://eugene-yeo.me/2012/12/4/django-tastypie-manytomany-through-part-2/

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111734/tastypie-add-element-to-a-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Cheers, mate. M2M through helped a lot!